# Why does next.js need runtime environment variables at build?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, environment-variables

After a bunch of false starts I've followed the [T3 stack](https://create.t3.gg/) approach to runtime [environment variables](https://create.t3.gg/en/usage/env-variables) for my next.js app, particularly to protect my `MONGODB_URI` secret by providing it only at runtime on the server.

env/server.js:

```js
import { createEnv } from "@t3-oss/env-nextjs";
import { z } from "zod";

export const env = createEnv({
  server: {
    NODE_ENV: z.enum(["development", "test", "production"]),
    MONGODB_URI: z.string().url(),
  },
  runtimeEnv: process.env,
});
```

lib/mongodb.ts:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import { env } from "@/env/server.mjs";

const uri = env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

if (!uri) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
clientPromise = client.connect();
export default clientPromise;
```

api/data/route.ts:

```js
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";

export async function GET() {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db();

  const data = await db
    .collection("data")
    .find({})
    .toArray();

  return Response.json({
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: data,
  });
}
```

That works locally, but causes a failure within the CI environment, because I've not defined the `MONGODB_URI` environment variable:

```
$ next build
❌ Invalid environment variables: { MONGODB_URI: [ 'Required' ] }
 ⨯ Failed to load next.config.mjs, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
> Build error occurred
```

I thought it would only be needed at runtime, not build. I can work around that by putting a dummy `MONGODB_URI` in `.env.production`, initially blank, but then looking like a dummy URL to satisfy the `zod` rule:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://host.placeholder.com/db
```

That works better, but still fails to build locally:

```
$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.1
   - Environments: .env.production

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
   Collecting page data  ...Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.host.placeholder.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.host.placeholder.com'
}
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/7)  [=   ]
Error occurred prerendering page "/api/data". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.host.placeholder.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17)
 ✓ Generating static pages (7/7)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /api/data/route: /api/data
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Why are what should be server-only dynamic elements being prerendered at build? Why is Mongo trying to make a connection at build time? (Presumably because of the pre-render). Why are my runtime secrets needed for build? It seems like they're being baked in, and won't be overridden by the actual environment.

I'd rather not expose these on my CI environment if I don't have to. Do I really need to?

Answer (score 1):

[Saber BoukHriss's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14852648/saber-boukhriss) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77558256/42974) got me on the right track, particularly around debugging pre-rendering issues.

Exporting a Route Segment Config from `api/data/route.ts` forces dynamic rather than pre-rendering of the API call. It's a bit of a blunt instrument so the other methods of triggering this (e.g. dynamic request parameters) may be better:

api/data/route.ts:

```js
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export async function GET() {

  ...

}
```

However, attempts are still made to connect to the database as `lib/mongodb.ts` still runs at build. Following some hints in [How to avoid executing page code during build?](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16840#discussioncomment-63483), I wrapped most of the file in a function. This is only then called if a page actually renders at build time, which it shouldn't if declared dynamic.

lib/mongodb.ts:

```js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import { env } from "@/env/server.mjs";

export function getClientPromise() {
  const uri = env.MONGODB_URI;
  const options = {};

  if (!uri) {
    throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
  }

  let client;
  let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();

  return clientPromise;
}

export default getClientPromise;
```

This still leaves `env/server.js` executing and validating at build time. This requires a valid but unused dummy MONGODB_URI in a `.env` file. `createEnv` has a parameter `[skipValidation][4]` which will prevent this. It comes with a warning that it is not encouraged and will lead to your types and runtime values being out of sync, but appears to be intended for build time.

env/server.mjs:

```js
import { createEnv } from "@t3-oss/env-nextjs";
import { z } from "zod";

export const env = createEnv({
  server: {
    NODE_ENV: z.enum(["development", "test", "production"]),
    MONGODB_URI: z.string().url(),
  },
  runtimeEnv: process.env,
  // skip validation at build time as secrets will not be available
  skipValidation: true,
});
```